# Algorithm CRC-12

Tags: c, crc

I am trying to do crc_table for 12-bit CRC and the algorithm, but always I got wrong results.

Can you help me? To create crc table I try:

```
void crcInit(void)
{
    unsigned short  remainder;
    int    dividend;
    unsigned char  bit;

    for (dividend = 0; dividend < 256; ++dividend)
    {
        remainder = dividend << 4;

        for (bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            if (remainder & 0x800)
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ 0x180D; //Polynomio of CRC-12
            }
            else
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1);
            }
        }
       crcTable[dividend] = remainder;
    }

}
```

I updated that and CRC algorithm is:

```
unsigned short crcFast(unsigned char const message[], int nBytes)
{
    unsigned short remainder = 0x0000;
    unsigned char  data;
    int  byte;


    /*
     * Divide the message by the polynomial, a byte at a time.
     */
    for (byte = 0; byte < nBytes; ++byte)
    {
        data = message[byte] ^ (remainder >> 4);
    remainder = crcTable[data] ^ (remainder << 8);
    }

    /*
     * The final remainder is the CRC.
     */
    return (remainder ^ 0);

}
```

But It isn't working.....

Comment: Is this from UIUC CS438 MP1? I'm in the same class. :)

Comment: Bear in mind that there are three algorithms that call themselves CRC-12.  So be sure you are implementing the right one for your purposes. The other common polynomials are: 0x180B and 0x180F.  Also check the initial value and final XOR value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem right:

```
if (remainder & 10000000)
```

It looks like you are intending this number to be binary, but  it is actually decimal. You should use a hex literal instead (0x80).

There also seem to be problems with this number, and with the size of the shift you do: This test should check if the high-order bit of the remainder is set. Since you are doing a 12-bit CRC, the mask should be 0x800 (binary 100000000000). And the shift above that should probably be:

```
remainder = dividend << 4;
```

to set the leftmost 8 bits of the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

The Boost library would have a CRC checksum algorithm already implemented, which can be used with different polynomials for division and numbers of bits. 
Use this link for further informations [Boost CRC](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/crc/crc.html#crc_basic).

An example implementation of myself would be:

```
string data = "S95I";
boost::crc_optimal<11, 0x571> crc;
crc.process_bytes(data.data(), data.size());
stringstream checksum;
checksum << (int)crc() % 1296;
string resultCheck = checksum.str();
```

To use a CRC with 12 bits you have to adopt the number of bits and the used polynomial, which can be found here: [Wikipedia CRC polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks)