# 3 character long checksum in HEX

Tags: algorithm, hex, theory, checksum

I have just theoretical question. my and my buddy are arguing about existence of 3 character long checksum (0...F) (i.e. 1AB, 2C3 etc.).

I am saying there is no known or commonly used algo/checksum but he does, it exist, but he does not know name.

Comment: That would be 12 bits. Such algorithms might exist though I've never personally encountered any - with only 4096 possible values they would be relatively weak at detecting errors.

Comment: Many years ago I saw one-byte checksums, which were often expressed as 3 octal digits. (Those old FORTRAN programmers, ya know.) But I don't recall ever seeing a 12-bit checksum. The only commonly used 12-bit quantity I can recall is in the old DOS File Allocation Table. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table

Comment: He also claims (idk why, that for K1607N0045753, checksum is 7EB) but now I am not sure why is messing with me

Comment: There are apparently at least three different algorithms called CRC-12. Depending on how much time you want to spend, you could track them down and see if any one returns the expected value for your test string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632051/algorithm-crc-12. A Google search of [crc 12 bit] returns some interesting results.